# How to avoid hard coding bootstrap server name/IP and port

Tags: apache-kafka

This is how a producer/consumer connects to broker:

```
// create instance for properties to access producer configs   
      Properties props = new Properties();
      
      //Assign localhost id
      props.put("bootstrap.servers", “localhost:9092");
```

Obviously, using localhost/IP/DNS name doesn't look to be highly available solution to me. Even port number for that matter. How can this hard coding be avoided?
Even something like Consul or Vault may not be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the problem. You'll need to provide one or more broker addresses for the bootstrap protocol. Then all brokers `advertised.listeners` will be returned. The highly available solution is to give multiple addresses or give one address that will be available.

Using a singular load balancer address could work. Consul could work as well. The address isn't a secret, so I wouldn't suggest using Vault unless you have SSL keys.